# Holiday customization

Tags: calendar

I'm following these instructions https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Holiday-Customizing.html to try and add Colombian holidays but I haven't been able to add holidays of the form "on  the 29th of June if its a Monday or on the next monday".

Can anyone help me with a holiday-sexp that will achieve this?

Note: I'm an elisp noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you're looking for is

```el
(holiday-sexp '(calendar-nth-named-day 1 1 6 year 29)
              "St Peter and St Paul")
```

I recommend you look at the function's documentation (`C-h f calendar-nth-named-day RET`) for an explanation of its arguments. Here, the symbol `year` is bound for you by `holiday-sexp`, so you don't need to define it.

Usually custom holidays are added to the list `holiday-other-holidays`, either in one swell foop like so:

```el
(setq holiday-other-holidays
      '((holiday-sexp '(calendar-nth-named-day 1 1 6 year 29)
                      "St Peter and St Paul")))
```

or incrementally, like so:

```el
(add-to-list 'holiday-other-holidays
             '(holiday-sexp '(calendar-nth-named-day 1 1 6 year 29)
                            "St Peter and St Paul"))
```

Note that the `calendar-nth-named-day` sexp must be quoted even within another quoted expression, as `holiday-sexp` `eval`s its arguments.

Comment: Can you fix the command for accessing the function documentation? It should be C-h f